# Python PIL How do I convert 1 bit deep images to RGBA?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgba

Exactly like the title. I take a single-band image of mode "1" and open it using

```
image = Image.open("picture.tif")
```

I then try to convert it to RGBA with

```
image.convert("RGBA")
```

And then whenever I check the mode of it using

```
print(image.mode)
```

I get that it's still "1". I've even tried this using "L" (which is another single-band image mode) and still no luck. No matter what I do, it won't convert. Searching the web only seems to reveal converting from "RGBA" to "1" but I haven't been able to find anything about the other way around. Is there ANY way (even outside Python) to convert 1 bit deep images to RGBA?

Help?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I get `img.mode` => `'1'`, then `img.convert('RGBA').mode` => `'RGBA'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`image.convert` doesn't change the mode of the image, it returns a new image with the new mode.

```
image = image.convert("RGBA")
```

From [the documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm):

> Unless otherwise stated, all methods return a new instance of the Image class, holding the resulting image.

Comment: So I would need to set a variable to that new image and save that image?

Comment: @TrentFaris242, you can either set it to a new variable or replace the original as I did in my example.

Comment: Thanks so much! If I had more reputation I'd vote this answer up. I've looked everywhere for an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to do in-place?

Comment: @QuaziIrfan no.  Even if there was a function for it, the RGBA image will take 32 times the memory that a 1-bit image does.