# python OpenCV: convert png to 16 Bit RGBA png image for E-pape Display

Tags: python, opencv, rgba

What is the way to convert RGB images to RGBA in python using OpenCV? My requirements are specific as I am trying to display an image on E-Paper Display. I need to convert an image to 16 bit RGBA. The code that I have written is converting the image but it's coming as all black. I have tried with [convert 1 bit deep images to RGBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270163/python-pil-how-do-i-convert-1-bit-deep-images-to-rgba) [NumPy convert 8-bit to 16/32-bit image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444334/numpy-convert-8-bit-to-16-32-bit-image) these solutions as well. I have to use **GMU image editor** on Linux to convert it manually then it works. Since I am trying to open a pdf and convert each page as an image to display it on E-Paper Diaplay. I can't go that way.

```
i = cv2.imread(FNAME, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
img = np.array(i, dtype=np.uint16) 
img *= 256 
filename = 'khrgb.png'
cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
```

Answer (score 0):

use cv2.cvtColor

```
rgba=cv2.cvtColor(i,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
```

Comment: rgba=cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(FNAME),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
# img = np.array(rgba, dtype=np.uint16)
# img *= 256
cv2.imwrite('khrgbi.png', rgba). Still just converting it to the RGB only not rgba.